# What are all the ways to win by card effect?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

With so many cards added in from ye original game:

What are new ways of winning by card effect?

I know of [Number 88: Gimmick Puppet of Leo](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_88:_Gimmick_Puppet_of_Leo), [Exodia](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Exodia_the_Forbidden_One), and [Destiny Board](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Destiny_Board), but I am not sure if any more have been added in.

Comment: *Technically* it's not by card effect, but by victory condition. This means most pf them can't been negated... working on an answer

Comment: But it's on the effect, so therefore, breakthrough skill could negate its ability.

Comment: Actually, [conditions can't be negated](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Condition). They are apart from effects

Comment: Enhanced my answer to clarify that really important part (that's even worthy of another question IMO)

Comment: The problem is that new victory conditions on cards are added all the time.

Answer (score 2):

> What are new ways of winning by card effect?

The following is a list of all the cards that have *victory conditions*<sup>1</sup> for winning that I recall:

- [Exodia](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Exodia): All five cards in hand and you win. This archetype has several variants, like Exodia Necross. One variant is [Exodius the Ultimate Forbidden Lord](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Exodius_the_Ultimate_Forbidden_Lord), which also has victory condition (similar, as you have to send all Exodia pieces to the GY to win).
- [Destiny Board](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Destiny%20Board): All five cards activated on your field, in order, and you win. This is an old set of cards, contemporary of Exodia.
- [Number 88: Gimmick Puppet of Leo](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_88:_Gimmick_Puppet_of_Leo): 3 counters on it and you win. You place them by detaching XYZ material to Leo, which is done by not having Spells or Traps and skipping your Battle phase. Part of the Gimmick Archetype. Its Chaos version, [Number C88: Gimmick Puppet Disaster Leo](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_C88:_Gimmick_Puppet_Disaster_Leo) also has win condition, when it has no XYZ material and your Opponent's LP are 2000 or lower.
- [Ghostrick Angel of Mischief](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Ghostrick_Angel_of_Mischief): With 10 XYZ material on it you win. Each turn you can add a Ghostrick card as material to it.
- [Jackpot 7](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Jackpot_7): All three copies banished by its effect and you win. To banish them your opp has to destroy them while set on your field.
- [Final Countdown](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Countdown): Just like the song, after 20 turns of its activation you win. Pay 2000 LP to activate. This card was recently limited as some decks were abusing of it.
- [Vennominaga the Deity of Poisonous Snakes](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Vennominaga_the_Deity_of_Poisonous_Snakes): also 3 venom counters on it and you win. Part of the Venom Archetype.
- [Holactie the Creator of Light](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Holactie_the_Creator_of_Light). Remember the Egyptian Gods? Meet *their* God. Summon it (by tributing the 3 Egyptian Gods) and you win.
- [Phantasm Spiral Assault](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Phantasm_Spiral_Assault): if your [Phantasm Spiral Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Phantasm_Spiral_Dragon) destroys 3 effect monsters while equipped with Phantasm Spiral equip cards you win.

These are only the "legal" or playable cards. For others like the restricted [Last Turn](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Turn) and other info about victory conditions and the winning player read [here](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Duel_winner).

---

<sup>1</sup> It is important to stress that [conditions are not card effects. Unlike card effects, conditions cannot be negated.](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Condition) This means that [Mind Drain](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_Drain) can't "negate" Exodia's "effect", as it is a condition.

This is the same for Number 88; if it has 3 counters you win, period. However, **you can cast Breakthrough Skill when Number 88's detach *effect* is activated**, and negate the placement of the counter (ruining his strategy as now it doesn't have enough material to get to 3). But the *condition* you can't negate.

Comment: Missed C88 cygnus, otherwise that's what I have too.

Comment: @Andrew :) you can also check if you want the [link](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Duel_winner) I included where a perhaps complete list is available.

Comment: C88 was included, its under the list of Number 88

Comment: Maybe this would be a useful post to be made Community Wiki?

Comment: @SK19 perhaps but the provided link already takes to a place where the list is continuously updated. Cards with victory conditions don't come out too often, as to justify many changes (where a comm wiki would be useful). If you wish you can suggest an edit to improve the post :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many cards that win the game by effect:

- [Number 88: Gimmick Puppet of Leo](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_88:_Gimmick_Puppet_of_Leo) - Gains counters by removing material, 3 counters and you win.
- [Exodia the Forbidden one](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Exodia_the_Forbidden_One) - Have this and the other 4 pieces in hand and you win.
- [Destiny Board](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Destiny_Board) - Have the other 4 spirit messages along with the board, spelling FINAL and you win.
- [Number C88: Gimmick Puppet Disaster Leo](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_C88:_Gimmick_Puppet_Disaster_Leo) - Wins if you have no material on it and the opponent is less than 2000 LP.
- [Exodius the Ultimate Forbidden Lord](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Exodius_the_Ultimate_Forbidden_Lord) - Similar to exodia, but he sends exodia to grave then wins when all pieces are in grave.
- [Vennominaga the Deity of Poisonous Snakes](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Vennominaga_the_Deity_of_Poisonous_Snakes) - If it gets three counters you win.
- [Final Countdown](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Countdown) - puts the game on a 20 turn clock, you win at the end of it.
- [Jackpot 7](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Jackpot_7) - If an opponent destroys three of these, you win.
- [Ghostrick Angel of Mischief](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Ghostrick_Angel_of_Mischief) - Wins when it has 10 material, other ghostrick monsters can be added as material, and any material they have gets added as well.
- [Phantasm Spiral Assault](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Phantasm_Spiral_Assault) - Wins when you have 3 different Phantasm Spirals (this and two others) equipped to the same [Phantasm Spiral Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Phantasm_Spiral_Dragon) and that monster destroys three opponent effect monsters.
- [Holactie the Creator of Light](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Holactie_the_Creator_of_Light) - Tribute all three god cards to summon this, summoning it wins the duel.

There is a card that could let either you or your opponent win:

- [Last Turn](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Turn) - Each player picks a monster, you from your field, them from their deck, the one left standing when they do battle wins the duel.

There is a card that can make you lose the duel:

- [Relay Soul](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Relay_Soul) - Summons a monster, you take no damage while that monster is in play and face up, but if the monster leaves the field you lose the duel.

And finally there are cards that win the match, like [Victory Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Victory_Dragon).

A full list of Duel Win cards is available [here](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Duel_winner).

Comment: did you edited your post to include the link I mentioned? I think our answer were already really similar...

Comment: @DarkCygnus Yes, though you didnt edit yours to add the card i mentioned i see.

Comment: OP asked for "ways of **winning** by card effect", so that's what I didn't included it (plus, those are in the link)

Comment: also, Victory Dragon is a tournament prize card, and can't be used in an official Duel. Last Turn is forbidden (and although I love its artwork and eff, I doubt it's coming back ever)

Comment: @DarkCygnus "During your End Phase, if your opponent's Life Points are 2000 or less, and this card has no Xyz Materials, you win the Duel." Also Traditional exists as a format, Last Turn, and VD for that matter, are both legal there. All match win cards have been tourney prizes to my knowledge. The question did not specify they wanted legality for competitive play, or a format anyways.

Comment: oh, yes I was not saying it was wrong, just commenting on those interesting cards you linked, OP didn't specify if wanted competitive winning condition so I agree with you. Also, why did you quote C88's condition?

Comment: @DarkCygnus Because C88 is the card I was referring to as missing from your list, it is winning by card effect.

Comment: I did [include](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/revisions/40121/1) it on my original post :) it is under the bullet point of Number 88, it was there originaly, but I didn't made a bullet point exclusively for it.

Comment: @DarkCygnus So you did, though as a separate card it should have a separate point, which is why I missed it, reading the list, not the content.