# Can effects (like Majesty's Fiend) prevent Exodia from winning?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Majesty's Fiend](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Majesty%27s_Fiend) is on the field.  It says

> Cannot be Special Summoned. Monster effects cannot be activated.

If all [Exodia](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Exodia_the_Forbidden_One) cards are collected, does Exodia's player win even though Majesty's Fiend prevents Monster effects from happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the new Sangan errata affect Exodia?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35388/how-does-the-new-sangan-errata-affect-exodia)

Comment: I think the duplicate target is too narrow since the question is very focused on Sangan.  I think reversing the duplicate target is better since this question (now edited) is more general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If all Exodia cards collected, does Exodia's player win?

**Yes**, the player will win.

The reason is because [Exodia](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Exodia_the_Forbidden_One) has a **win condition** not an effect. From its [rulings](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Exodia_the_Forbidden_One), emphasis mine:

> When you add the fifth piece to your hand and declare that you win the Duel, **you are using a victory condition. You are not activating a monster's effect**, so "Divine Wrath" and "Gladiator Beast War Chariot" cannot be activated

This means that [Majesty's Fiend](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Majesty%27s_Fiend), who negates *effects*, won't be able to prevent the player from wining. From its text, emphasis mine:

> Cannot be Special Summoned. **Monster effects** cannot be activated.

Comment: I've been playing YuGiOh for years and this is the first time I know about "victory condition"!

Comment: There are a few cards with such conditions. See [this answer of mine](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/40121/22373) for a list of those (I even happen to mention Exodia at the end). Welcome to Board & Card games BTW :D